# how to send ctrl a+c using python?

Tags: python, terminal, gnu-screen

I need to find out how to send `ctrl a+c` using python to make a new screen using GNU Screen I'm lost i have not found any code that will get this working. I need to control GNU Screen using python.

**More info**
    http://lifehacker.com/5652409/how-to-run-multiple-applications-in-a-single-terminal-window

Answer (score 1):

try with [sendcontrol()](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html#spawn-sendcontrol) from pexpext module.

```
import pexpect

child = pexpect.spawn ('screen')
child.sendcontrol('a');
child.send('c');
```

The [documentation](http://www.noah.org/wiki/Pexpect) has many examples.